# Primary key error in using auto increment in SQL Server CE

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, primary-key, identity

I have set the primary key field as auto increment and identity in SQL Server Compact and when I insert new record to it, I don't fill the identity value and pass it ass null.
but when running the application I get this error :

> "Server-generated keys and server-generated values are not supported
>   by SQL Server Compact."

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The question is what should I do to insert auto increment primary key record to my table?!

Comment: My question was slightly sarcastic, because you didn't really state one and the error message is quite clear: it just isn't supported. To avoid problems your best option would be to use `Guid` as ErikEJ states

Answer (score 2):

With SQL Compact 3.5 you must use Guid as the ID, as int IDENTITY is not supported when using Entity Framework. int works with SQL Compact 4.0, however.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this error you should leave The ID column in your insertion ***alone***.
if you have a TABLE with Three COLUMNs, you should do your insertion LIKE this:
the TABLE Declaration:

```
CREATE TABLE Books 
(
   ID INT IDENTITY, 
   Name NVARCHAR(200), 
   PublishYear DATETIME
)
```

And Insert your record Like this:

```
INSERT INTO Books (Name, PublishYear) 
VALUES (N'Boof-e koor', '1937-10-28 12:30:00.000')
```

Again, you shall NOT mention the INDENTITY Column in your insertion statement.

Comment: Dear Soheil, i am using entity frame work, and i use add addObject method for it. i need  to create an object of my entity and its not with me to ignore Identity column in insertion